# Does the pseudoinverse of $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ commute with $A$ when $A$ is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A^+\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the [(Moore-Penrose) pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $A$ and that $AA^t=A^tA$. Does there hold $$AA^+=A^+A?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: the previous proof has a serious flaw and is now corrected.**

Let $A=USV^\ast$ be a singular value decomposition of $A$, where $S=\sigma_1 I_{m_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus \sigma_k I_{m_k}$ for some distinct singular values $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k$. Since $A$ is normal, we have $US^2U^\ast = AA^\ast = A^\ast A=VS^2V^\ast$, or equivalently, $(V^\ast U)S^2=S^2(V^\ast U)$. Therefore $W:=V^\ast U$ is a block diagonal unitary matrix that has conforming partitioning to $S$. As each diagonal block of $S$ is some $\sigma_j I_{m_j}$, the three matrices $W, W^\ast$ and $S$ commute. It follows that $A=USWU^\ast$ and $A^+=UW^\ast S^+U^\ast$ commute.

Comment: @LeonLampret My previous answer contains a serious mistake. while it is now corrected, please feel free to unaccept this answer if you wish.

Comment: What was the mistake that you mention?

Comment: @LeonLampret In the previous revision, I wrongly wrote that $A$ can be orthogonally diagonalised because it is normal. This is true if all eigenvalues of $A$ are real, but wrong in general. A classical counterexample is a $2\times2$ rotation matrix for an angle that is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Because
$$
A^{\dagger}=\lim_{\lambda\searrow0}(A^TA+\lambda I)^{-1}A^T
$$
(see a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247129/why-would-a-text-ta-lambda-i-1a-text-t-be-close-to-a-dagger-w?rq=1)). By your hypothesis, $A^TA=AA^T$; also, $A(A^TA+\lambda I)=(A^TA+\lambda I)A$, which implies $(A^TA+\lambda I)^{-1}A=A(A^TA+\lambda I)^{-1}$.